# Как перенести Pattern в Canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Есть Pattern который создается на точках 0,0 как его переместить на координаты круга?

```
const nicepic = '1.png';
pattern = ctx.createPattern(nicepic, 'norepeat');
ctx.arc(150, 200, 100, 0, Math.PI*2);
ctx.fillStyle = pattern;
ctx.fill();
```